# A connected open set containing open sets without their boundaries 2

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Is it possible to have an infinite number of disjoint open sets $V_{n}$ contained in a bounded and connected open set $W$, and such that each $ \partial V_{n}\subset \partial W $? Here $\partial$ means boundary and the sets are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ $(n>1)$ .

Comment: What topological space are these sets in?

Comment: If $\bar W$ is compact, it isn't.

Comment: Hint: Each $V_n$ is relatively closed in $W$ and also open. What does it tell you about its complement in $W$?

Comment: I corrected, the sets are in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: So there is not even one such $V_{n}$ beside $W$. Thanks.